# Decoupling 2 Tightly Coupled Classes, Basket and Discount

Tags: object-oriented-design, circular-dependency

I have two tightly coupled classes `Basket` and `Discount`.

`Basket` is responsible for keeping track of the items in a shopping basket, keeping track of any discount codes applied, and calculating the final bill.

`Discount` is an interface that has many implementing classes such as `BuyOneGetOneFreeDiscount`, `FlatDiscount`, `MealDealDiscount` and so on. Therefore the logic of if a discount is eligible, and the amount of the discount is highly dependent on the specific instance of the class, and so I believe that logic should live in `Discount`.

So we have two tightly coupled classes that have a circular dependency

- `Discount` needs access to the instance of `Basket` when determining if the `Discount` can be applied or not
- Once applied `Basket` owns the instance of `Discount` and lists it in the final itemised bill.

I realise this is a problem since the whole point of OO is to have loosely coupled classes to avoid huge breaking changes. How can I decouple these classes?

Comment: Does `Discount` *really* need access to `Basket`? Or does it need access to some piece (or pieces) of the `Basket` internal state?

Comment: I had thought about this, it only really needs access to the collection of items inside `Basket`. However, I'd have to give it a copy of that collection, which for large baskets would be expensive. In addition, it's exposing the internals of `Basket` to `Discount` which means if we ever decide to change the way items in `Basket` are stored, we'd have to change `Discount` too.

Comment: It sounds as if your Basket may be doing too many things and violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html) -- consider whether it makes logical sense for it to be responsible for calculating the final bill;  imagine the role of a basket in a real-world situation;  i.e. a customer carrying a basket in a physical retail store is only using it to move items to the Point-of-Sale which is responsible for calculating the bill;  a basket in the real-world doesn't have any role in financial transactions.

Comment: You're right about this, thanks for pointing it out, seemed to be a blind spot of mine!

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, I don't know whether it fits your requirements, but how about splitting the `Discount`?

I think it is not a stretch to split the `Discount` into generic discounts that can be applied to different `Basket`s, and `AppliedDiscount` as something that is not "generic" anymore, but is applied to the specific basket. This does not need to be subclassed as it no longer has different behavior for different kinds of generic `Discount`s.

So there are no more circular dependencies for the price of an additional abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

> `Basket` is responsible for keeping track of the items in a shopping basket, keeping track of any discount codes applied, and calculating the final bill.

You can either split the `Basket` into two named types (say a simple item container  `Basket` and a discount-selecting `Checkout`) or into a named complex type and a dumb container of items.

> `Discount` needs access to the instance of Basket when determining if the Discount can be applied or not

Whichever you chose above, `Discount` only needs access to the container of items. It doesn't make sense for a `Discount` interact with the other possible discounts. What if several could be applied but you have to choose the best for the customer? No individual `Discount` should be trying to do this.

> ... However, I'd have to give it a copy of that collection, which for large baskets would be expensive.

I can't think of any language in which this is true. If you can't pass a container of items around by reference, you can expose some kind of iterator or iterable, or you can have the `Discount` provide a predicate which is applied to the items.

Remember the `Discount` should anyway not be mutating the collection of items - it should just be producing a description of whether it matches, which items participated, whether it's exclusive and the cash value of the discount.